# Having troubles with this problem: Set theory, cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A$ is a set of functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ and for every $f,g \in A$ the set $X=\{n\in \mathbb N: f(n) \neq g(n) \}$ is finite, then $A$ is countable or finite.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chose $f \in A$ then any $g \in A$ differs from $f$ in finitely many places. There are only countably many finite sets and for each there are only countably many values for another function $g$ to take.

Comment: Deleted the previous comment, did not understand the hypothesis:) good answer!